# Jquery Bootstrap datepicker UI broken in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have implemented bootstrap datepicker, It works fine in IE but chrome it looks like below screen.
The issue only with its UI. Functionally it works but UI is not displaying correctly. 
[image]

Please suggest fixes.

Comment: Could you provide us with a snippet or JSFiddle with the code you are using, making sure that the problem is obvious.

Comment: What datepicker plugin are you using? Please provide a link to the github or other source page.

Comment: Following are version I am using
Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.4.0, bootstrap-datepicker3.css, jquery-2.2.4.js